# Closure of sequences that go to $0$ at finite order

Tags: general-topology

I have the following exercise.

Let $X=\prod_{n\ge0}\mathbb{R}$ and let
$$A=\{ \{x_i\}_{i\ge0}\in X : \exists N\in\mathbb{N}, i>N \implies x_i=0 \}.$$

Compute the closure of $A$ in $X$ in the product topology and in the box topology.

So, I know the definitions of the $2$ topologies but this doesn't help a lot. I have the "feeling" that in the box topology $A$ is closed, so I tried to prove that $X\backslash A$ is open. I used sets of this form $\prod_{i\ge0}(-\infty,a_i)\cup(b_i,\infty)$ but I cannot find a way to write $X\backslash A$ as countable intersections or unions of this type of neighborhoods. Will something like this work?

For the product topology I am completely stuck. So this is what I can prove. By taking $(X,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ any sequence that converges to $0$ can be a limit of a sequence in $A$ but I am not sure that the closure is just the sequences that converge to $0$ and nothing more. Also I am not sure how to prove that the topology in $(X,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is compatible with the product topology.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What is $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_\infty$ here?

Comment: It's the supremum norm.

Comment: Then it's incompatible with the product topology, and infinite on "most" sequences.

Comment: Is it compatible with the product topology? Then $A$ is dense? I do not see that.

Comment: Incompatible. Stefan explained how to see that $A$ is dense with respect to the product topology.

Comment: Oh, right, I misread it. The closure of $A$ with the sup norm is the set of all sequences converging to $0$?

Comment: You would have to say how you deal with $\lVert x\rVert_\infty = +\infty$. If you do that sensibly, then yes, the closure of the space of finitely supported sequences is the space of sequences converging to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure of $A$ in the product topology is everything, so $A$ is dense. That's because if you take any basic open set $\prod_{i=i_1,...,i_n} U_i$, it contains some sequence from $A$, as you can choose one point from each of the finitely many $U_i$ and let it otherwise be $0$.

In the box topology the situation is different. Given a sequence $(x_n)_n$ which is distinct from $0$ for infinitely many coordinates (i.e. a point not in $A$), can you find an open box around this point not containing any sequence from $A$? This would show that $A$ is closed.

Comment: Oh, $A$ is dense? I see but I didn't expect that. I also see your point in the box topology, I can find a neibourhood of an element not in $A$ that doesn't intersect $A$ so the complement is closed. Thanks!

Comment: In the above comment I mean open instead of closed of course.